# How to send a json dictionary as a field in a Multipart Form API Requests call?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a POST API call using requests in Python, but I'm running into a problem with how to pass both json data and multipart file at the same time. I can get it to work in Insomnia, but then recreating that in a Python module with variables that I am populating is difficult.

The API documentation says there are two parameters -- `file` and `metadata`. `metadata` is a json object that includes keys including `matter`, `title`, and `description`. `matter` is required. All of the options that I've looked at result with a response that the `matter` parameter is missing.

I've tried using `requests_toolkit` and it's multipart encoder:

```
matter_id = 5
payload_data = {}
payload_data['matter'] = matter_id
mp_encoder = MultipartEncoder(fields={'metadata': "{" + str(payload_data) + "}", 'file': (None, open(file_path, 'rb'), 'text/plain') })
response = requests.post(url, data=mp_encoder, headers={'Content-Type': mp_encoder.content_type}, auth=(apiuser, apipassword))
```

If I didn't use `str(payload_data)`, I got errors about encoding. I tried adding the extra `{}` but that didn't seem to make that happen either.

I've tried with just `requests`:

```
matter_id = 5
payload_data = {}
payload_data['matter'] = matter_id
file_content = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}
payload = {'metadata': payload_data} 
response = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=file_content, auth=(apiuser, apipassword))
```

I also tried `payload=payload`, `params=payload` instead of `data=payload` and no luck.

In the above example, I tried combining the `payload` and `file_content` into one dictionary to pass in the `files` parameter:

```
payloadv2 = {'file': (None, open(file_path, 'rb')), 'metadata': (None, {'matter': matter_id})}
```

And that also didn't work.

Comment: Just a note, `params` [argument](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request) are used for query string contained in the url, not for post data, and there doesn't seem to be a `payload` argument for `requests.request` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert python dict to JSON string representation using `json.dumps(payload_data)` instead of concatenating `"{"` and `"}"` since the latter might be error-prone.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @oeter. That's what I needed. I changed the line to `mp_encoder = MultipartEncoder(fields={'metadata': json.dumps(payload_data), 'file': ('file', open(file_path, 'rb')) })` and that did it. Thanks!